# Why, when an synthetic event is triggered, events related to it do not occur?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a code like this, it raised my question:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
  console.log("Registered unhandledrejection event");
}); /// event listener
var unhandleEvent = new PromiseRejectionEvent("unhandledrejection", {
  promise: new Promise(function(a, b) {}),
  reason: "404"
}); /// creating event of unhandled promise rejection
setTimeout(() => {
  window.dispatchEvent(unhandleEvent)
}, 3000); /// calling our event
```

But we are not getting an error. Why? If you do the same thing, but explicitly cause a rejection in the promise, we get an error:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
  console.log("Registered unhandledrejection event");
}); /// event listener
var unhandleEvent = new Promise(function(a, b) {
  b("301")
}); /// creating unhandled promise rejection
```

Is there any reason why this happens?

P.S. The error is not displayed in the snippet, it must be viewed in the browser console.

Comment: I see the same log message in both snippets.

Comment: Never mind, I had to go to the real console to see the error message in addition to the `console.log()` messages.

Comment: You've got it backwards. The error triggers the event, the event doesn't cause the error.

Comment: It's like asking why your mouse button doesn't go down when you trigger a synthetic `mousedown` event.

Comment: @barmar hmm, look at this `Allowing the unhandledrejection event to bubble will eventually result in an error message being output to the console.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

Comment: Hmm, do synthetic events bubble? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent says they do, so that's not it, either.

Comment: @barmar You say that the error fires the event, but it doesn’t: take an example where the error pops up and add `event.preventDefault()` to the event listener - this will eliminate the error as a consequence of the "unhandledrejection" event.

Comment: That was a mistake, you already pointed out the documentation.